# Implementing Parallel Stream to get all the student details

Tags: list, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

I wrote a service to fetch the complete details of students of all class. The service is working fine, but the issue is that it is taking too long to fetch the complete details. My code is as given below

```
List<StudentsDetails> allStudentsDetails = Lists.newArrayList();

List<ClassDetails> allClassDetailsDetails = getAllClassDetails();

allClassDetailsDetails.forEach(classDetailsDetails-> {
    StudentsDetails studentsDetails = new StudentsDetails();
    studentsDetails.setClassName(classDetailsDetails.getClassName());
    List<Student> allStudents = studentService.getAllStudentsByClass(classDetailsDetails.getClassName());
    studentsDetails.setAllStudents(allStudents);        
    allStudentsDetails.add(studentsDetails);
});
```

**My question**

Is it good to use Java8 parallel stream in this scenario, does that really improves the performance, also how can I implement parallel stream in this approach.

Comment: Test it. But not sure it brings better performances, as I believe the performance lack will often come from the data layer instead of the application one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you parallelize the operation, but the performance benefits cannot be guaranteed, as it also depends on the external database.

```
Function<ClassDetails, StudentsDetails> fetchStudentDetials = classDetailsDetails -> {
    StudentsDetails studentsDetails = new StudentsDetails();
    studentsDetails.setClassName(classDetailsDetails.getClassName());
    List<Student> allStudents = studentService.getAllStudentsByClass(classDetailsDetails.getClassName());
    studentsDetails.setAllStudents(allStudents);
    return studentsDetails;
};

List<StudentsDetails> allStudentsDetails = allClassDetailsDetails
        .parallelStream()
        .map(fetchStudentDetials)
        .collect(toList());
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.....do we have any side effects implementing parrallel stream in my approach....

Comment: No. Also note, parallel streams only benefit if you have huge collection, or long running tasks. Please take a look `@Mạnh Quyết Nguyễn` has to say. Although `parallel` is not required in his solution, as numbers of `ClassDetails` would be fairly low.

Answer (score 0):

The code slow comes from DB access.

First, You should index your DB.

Second, if your student database is not very high, I recommend you to get it in one shot:

```
List<Student> findStudentByClassNameIn(List<String> classNames);
```

Then map your students to your class.

```
// Map class name with its student
Map<String, List<Student>> stdMap = listStudents().stream().collect(groupingBy(Student::getClassName), toList());

List<StudentsDetails> allStudentsDetails = allClassDetailsDetails.stream()
        .parallel()
        .map(c -> new StudentDetails(stdMap.get(c.getClassName()))
        .collect(toList());
```

Third, if your student data is too large to get in one shot, then break down to get for example 30 classes data at once.

Answer (score 0):

Try my library [AbacusUtil](https://github.com/landawn/AbacusUtil). It should be tens of times faster than the code in original question:

```
List<StudentsDetails> allStudentsDetails = StreamEx.of(allClassDetailsDetails).parallel(maxThreadNum) // genernally maxThreadNum = 30 is a good choice.
    .map(c -> new StudentsDetails(c.getClassName(), studentService.getAllStudentsByClass(c.getClassName())))
    .toList();
```